# Lots of Failure Alerts on my DC

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, windows-event-log

I am receiving lots of Failure Audit logs on my DC, can you guide me - how should i identify the culprit.

Please see the below print-screen for more detail. The logon type is 3, that means it is a network logon. I have identify the Workstation from the log, but how should i prove who or which process is sending broadcast with logon authentication to my DC. The Anti-virus is also updated.

Note:- The Workstation is in Workgroup.[image]

Answer (score 1):

use tcp view http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx on the workstation it will tell you the process that is talking to the dc.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, your anti virus is updated, just perform virus scanning on all workstations or turn on IIS logging.

Refer the following link for error event: [event id 4625](http://eventid.net/display-eventid-4625-source-Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing-eventno-9984-phase-1.htm)

The thread can also be monitored by a third party tool.